# Finding URL from <a> using PHP

Tags: php, html

I need to find every occurrence of URL coded in "href" part of html  tag using PHP.

As result, I want to get array of every url. Tried a little of this, but it finds only "href=" starting thing. I know that my code is very basic, but I don't know how to improve or change this, to make it works. Thanks for all help.

```
<?php

$array = [];  
$string = file_get_contents("file.html");  
$begin = 0;  
$end = 0;

do {  
    $begin = strpos($string, "<a href=\"", $end + 1);  
    $end = strpos($string, "\"", $begin + 6);  
    $array[] = substr($string, ($begin + 6), ($end - $begin - 6));
} while ($begin !== false && $end !== false);
```

Comment: have you tried using Regular Expressions? Or better still, a HTML/DOM parser?

Answer (score 1):

Use [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) for that, [not Regex!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

```php
$html = file_get_contents('file.html');

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$tags = $xpath->query('//a');
$links = [];

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $links[] = $tag->getAttribute('href');
}
```

[Example](https://onlinephp.io?s=fY_BS8MwFMbPBvI_PIrQ9FDD5s1mFWEHDxt62EEYY8Q2W4pNE9vXORH_d5Nm4ElDDnn5vt_H98S9044SSq41mhYWIISAx816RYmom1NJyZWQoHt1WCQa0d1xrs7SuFbdVNbwWVKumu4NZoJL7xU8Mv8h8wsyjwglG90M4G9nEdqg_IneJpSEbsVUuLbG9-3UByyf1ktbjUZ1yLIiSnnZWlkHN5tWyyJ0dhL1L_by7EcW_Bcd5XHwcvTl5fuo-k-Wci7TKTj0C_p2N9kPtley0sAiJwcIjwy-KAF_on27C4H-Py-PCh8Q--Z1RMXSsOcU-x2yTrLf16NxLFJZ8QM%2C&v=8.2.1)